# TabLayout only in Toolbar in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I created a TabLayout referring to this tutorial:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

My xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E0E0E0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.blabla.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:logo="@drawable/test_24px"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        app:title="@string/app_name"
        app:titleMarginStart="24dp"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />

</LinearLayout><!--android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout-->
```

So my TabLayout is inside the Toolbar. But I just want to have this in the landscape mode to save space. But in the normal portrait mode I  want the TabLayout underneath the Toolbar.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You should use two tablayout and toggle them on configuration change ..

Comment: @ADM: How do I toggle them?

Comment: Just Visible/Gone Tablayout and set To ViewPager . See if that works . I am  not sure about it as adapter already called . Give it a try.

Comment: @ADM It worked, thanks!

Comment: Bravo .. good luck ..